# XPATH - retrieve data that has no class and not within specific html tag

Tags: xpath

```
<li class="">
                            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
                            Smoking allowed:
                            <strong class="">No</strong>
                        </li>
```

I am trying to say here: "if you see the text "Smoking allowed:" then return the value in the strong tag below it.

I am trying stuff like this but to no avail:

```
//li[text()[contains(., 'Smoking allowed:')]
```

I have also tried:

```
//li[contains(., 'Smoking allowed:')]/following-sibling:i
```

I need to use contains as there ae spaces in the text, so would rather not be too exact when matching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there is always only one `strong` in an `li`, you can find `li` element that contains "Smoking allowed" and then return `strong` element in that `li` like this:

```
//li[text()[contains(.,'Smoking allowed')]]/strong
```

or if there can be multiple `strong` elements and you're only interested in the one located after the text "Smoking allowed" :

```
//li/text()[contains(.,'Smoking allowed')]/following-sibling::strong[1]
```

Brief Explanation:

- **`//li`**: find `li` elements anywhere in the document
- **`/text()[contains(.,'Smoking allowed')]`**: then from such `li`, find child text nodes that contains text 'Smoking allowed'
- **`/following-sibling::strong[1]`**: then from such text nodes, select the closest following-sibling `strong` element

**<kbd>[xpathtester demo](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/765ddf3ca8be08f3d61ff7c1f1b378ab)</kbd>**